# Value does not increment correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to increment a variable in Objective-C. This would seem to be an easy:

```
dataPos++
```

but when I do this, the value increases very strangely:

```
dataPos: 1,
dataPos: 2,
dataPos: 3,
dataPos: 4,
dataPos: 12,
dataPos: 185273100`
```

This is my code:

```
int dataPos = 0;
uint8_t temparray[1];
for (int x=0; x < mapX; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < mapY; y++) {
        for (int z=0; z < mapZ; z++) {
            [mapdata getBytes:&temparray range:NSMakeRange(dataPos, dataPos+1)];
            dataPos++;
            NSLog(@"dataPos: %d", dataPos);
            map[x][y][z] = temparray[0];
        }   
    }  
}
```

mapData is an NSMutableData, with about 4194308 bytes in it, and map[][][] is a uint8_t array.

I have tried cleaning the build folder, building on both the simulator (Value never increases, stays at 1), and the device.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMakeRange` takes a position *and length*, not a start and end position. You're likely reading too much data into `temparray` and overwriting `dataPos` in the process. See the [Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) for more info, and rewrite your code to read:

```
// snip
[mapdata getBytes:&temparray range:NSMakeRange(dataPos, 1)];
// snip
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overflowing your `temparray` and overwriting your integer.

You've allocated 1 byte, and call `getBytes` with it, copying  `dataPos+1` bytes to it. You probably mean to use `NSMakeRange(dataPos, 1)` since the [second parameter to NSMakeRange is the length of the range, not the end position](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange).